# how to split data by group?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following data

```
user_id, item_id
1, 2
1, 3
2, 5,
2, 4
1, 4
```

I want to split data  with a constraint:

each user must be in either train set or test set, but not both

so `[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]] / [[2,5],[2,4]]` is valid split
but `[[1,2],[2,5][1,4]] / [[1,3]... ]` is not a valid split because user has been split up

I'm not sure if `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` does support it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want have fixed proportion users in train and test you need get unique users and split users. Below pseudo code

```
train_ids, test_ids = train_test_split(unique_users)
train_X = data[data.user_id==train_ids]
test_X = data[data.user_id==test_ids]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think correct syntax is `data[data.user.isin(train_ids)]`